# Exchange data between fragments and activities - NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments

My application has a log-in function. When the log-in is successful, you navigate to the first page of the application that has a navigation drawer, so most of my screens are fragments, not activities and are being called by the `BaseActivity.java`.

I have the fragment `AddShopFragment` in which a user can add info about a shop and save it. In this fragment, I have a button named `moreinfo`. When you press it, you navigate to the activity named `AddMoreInfoForShopActivity`. This activity has a button named `lessinfo` that navigates you to `BaseActivity` and then this activity sends you and the data to the `AddShopFragment` fragment.

Until now, I managed to save a shop using the data from BOTH, activity and fragment. So, I can exchange those info between *Activity for more data - BaseActivity - Fragment that saves the data* .

Right now the only thing that has left, is to when press the button for more data and then press the button for less data, I don't want all the data from my `AddShopFragment` fragment to being removed.

So, I tried sending the data from `AddShopFragment` fragment to `AddMoreInfoForShopActivity` activity, then to `BaseActivity` and then to `AddShopFragment` again, so that I can fill the textareas and spinners.

**Note that the data that I am trying to display in the fragment are:
category, subcategory, shopname, location, email and telephone.**

**Before trying to display those data, all the info were being saved correctly in Parse, so the error is related only with sending those specific data to the other activities and back to the fragment.**

---

This is the exception that occurs when the log-in of the user is successful, so the app has to navigate to the first fragment that I have already set:

```
01-27 21:25:32.911  10009-10009/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all, PID: 10009
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.BaseActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all.AddShopFragment.onCreateView(AddShopFragment.java:271)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:548)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error line is:

`if(!getArguments().getString("category").equals("Select:")&&getArguments().getString("category")!=null&&!getArguments().getString("category").isEmpty()&&!getArguments().getString("category").equals("")) {`

---

The `AddShopFragment` part of code that sends the data that we don't want to loose:

```
moreinfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent intent;
                        intent = new Intent(AddShopFragment.this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), AddMoreInfoForShopActivity.class);

                        if (category.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select:") || category.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty() || category.getSelectedItem().toString() == null)
                            intent.putExtra("category", "");
                        else
                            intent.putExtra("category", category.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        if (subcategory_bar.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select:") || subcategory_bar.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty() || subcategory_bar.getSelectedItem().toString() == null){
                            if (subcategory_restaurant.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Select:") || subcategory_restaurant.getSelectedItem().toString().isEmpty() || subcategory_restaurant.getSelectedItem().toString() == null) {
                                intent.putExtra("subcategory", "");
                            }
                            else
                                intent.putExtra("subcategory", subcategory_restaurant.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        }
                        else{
                            intent.putExtra("subcategory", subcategory_bar.getSelectedItem().toString());
                        }

                        if (shopname.getText().toString() == null || shopname.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                            intent.putExtra("shopname", "");
                        else
                            intent.putExtra("shopname", shopname.getText().toString());

                        if (location.getText().toString() == null || location.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                            intent.putExtra("location", "");
                        else
                            intent.putExtra("location", location.getText().toString());

                        if (email.getText().toString() == null || email.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                            intent.putExtra("email", "");
                        else
                            intent.putExtra("email", email.getText().toString());

                        if (telephone.getText().toString() == null || telephone.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                            intent.putExtra("telephone", "");
                        else
                            intent.putExtra("telephone", telephone.getText().toString());

//                        if (flag_photo == true)
//                            intent.putExtra("photo", image);

                        startActivity(intent);

                        //finish();
                    }
                });
```

---

The `AddMoreInfoForShopActivity` part of code that gets the data from the fragment:

```
if (getIntent() != null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();

            category = intent.getStringExtra("category");
            subcategory = intent.getStringExtra("subcategory");
            shopname = intent.getStringExtra("shopname");
            location = intent.getStringExtra("location");
            email = intent.getStringExtra("email");
            telephone = intent.getStringExtra("telephone");
        }
        else{
            category = "";
            subcategory = "";
            shopname = "";
            location = "";
            email = "";
            telephone = "";
        }
```

---

The `AddMoreInfoForShopActivity` part of code that sends to `BaseActivity` the data:

```
Intent i = new Intent(AddMoreInfoForShopActivity.this,
                        BaseActivity.class);

                //pass data to an intent to load a specific fragment of reader activity
                i.putExtra("opening", OpeningTime);
                i.putExtra("closing", ClosingTime);
                i.putExtra("dresscoding", dresscoding2);
                i.putExtra("music", music2);
                i.putExtra("otherinfo", otherinfo2);
                i.putExtra("facebook", fb2);
                i.putExtra("moneyperperson", moneyperperson2);
                i.putExtra("smokingarea", smokingarea2);
                i.putExtra("parking", parking2);
                i.putExtra("creditcards", creditcards2);
                i.putExtra("takeout", takeout2);
                i.putExtra("delivery", delivery2);
                i.putExtra("freewifi", freewifi2);
                i.putExtra("happyhour", happyhour2);
                i.putExtra("outdoorseating", outdoorseating2);
                i.putExtra("reservations", reservations2);
                i.putExtra("appropriategroups", appropriategroup2);
                i.putExtra("appropriatekids", appropratekids2);

                i.putExtra("category", category);
                i.putExtra("subcategory", subcategory);
                i.putExtra("shopname", shopname);
                i.putExtra("location", location);
                i.putExtra("email", email);
                i.putExtra("telephone", telephone);

                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);

                startActivity(i);
```

---

My `BaseActivity` part that gets the data from activity **and** sends is back to the fragment:

```
 if (getIntent() != null) {
            Intent i = getIntent();

            String opening = i.getStringExtra("opening");
            String closing = i.getStringExtra("closing");
            String dresscoding = i.getStringExtra("dresscoding");
            String music = i.getStringExtra("music");
            String otherinfo = i.getStringExtra("otherinfo");
            String facebook = i.getStringExtra("facebook");
            String moneyperperson = i.getStringExtra("moneyperperson");
            String smokingarea = i.getStringExtra("smokingarea");
            String creditcards = i.getStringExtra("creditcards");
            String parking = i.getStringExtra("parking");
            String takeout = i.getStringExtra("takeout");
            String delivery = i.getStringExtra("delivery");
            String freewifi = i.getStringExtra("freewifi");
            String happyhour = i.getStringExtra("happyhour");
            String outdoorseating = i.getStringExtra("outdoorseating");
            String reservations = i.getStringExtra("reservations");
            String appropriategroup = i.getStringExtra("appropriategroups");
            String appropratekids = i.getStringExtra("appropriatekids");

            String category = i.getStringExtra("category");
            String subcategory = i.getStringExtra("subcategory");
            String shopname = i.getStringExtra("shopname");
            String location = i.getStringExtra("location");
            String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
            String telephone = i.getStringExtra("telephone");

            Fragment fragment = new AddShopFragment();

                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("opening", opening);
                bundle.putString("closing", closing);
                bundle.putString("dresscoding", dresscoding);
                bundle.putString("music", music);
                bundle.putString("otherinfo", otherinfo);
                bundle.putString("facebook", facebook);
                bundle.putString("moneyperperson", moneyperperson);
                bundle.putString("smokingarea", smokingarea);
                bundle.putString("creditcards", creditcards);
                bundle.putString("parking", parking);
                bundle.putString("takeout", takeout);
                bundle.putString("delivery", delivery);
                bundle.putString("freewifi", freewifi);
                bundle.putString("happyhour", happyhour);
                bundle.putString("outdoorseating", outdoorseating);
                bundle.putString("reservations", reservations);
                bundle.putString("appropriategroups", appropriategroup);
                bundle.putString("appropriatekids", appropratekids);

                bundle.putString("category", category);
                bundle.putString("subcategory", subcategory);
                bundle.putString("shopname", shopname);
                bundle.putString("location", location);
                bundle.putString("email", email);
                bundle.putString("telephone", telephone);

            //set Fragmentclass Arguments
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
            //}
        }
```

---

And at last, this is the way I get data from `BaseActivity` and trying to display it in my screen - `AddShopFragment`:

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {

                    if (!getArguments().getString("category").equals("Select:") && getArguments().getString("category") != null && !getArguments().getString("category").isEmpty() && !getArguments().getString("category").equals("")) {
                        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        category.setAdapter(adapter);

                        int spinnerPostion = adapter.getPosition(getArguments().getString("category"));
                        category.setSelection(spinnerPostion);
                        spinnerPostion = 0;

                        if (getArguments().getString("category").equals("Bar")) {
                            subcategory_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            subcategory_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.subcategory_bar, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            subcategory_bar.setAdapter(adapter2);

                            if (!getArguments().getString("subcategory").equals("Select:") && getArguments().getString("subcategory") != null && !getArguments().getString("subcategory").isEmpty() && !getArguments().getString("subcategory").equals("")) {
                                int spinnerPostion2 = adapter2.getPosition(getArguments().getString("subcategory"));
                                subcategory_bar.setSelection(spinnerPostion2);
                                spinnerPostion2 = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        if (getArguments().getString("category").equals("Restaurant")) {
                            subcategory_restaurant.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            subcategory_label.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.array.subcategory_restaurant, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                            adapter3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            subcategory_restaurant.setAdapter(adapter3);

                            if (!getArguments().getString("subcategory").equals("Select:") && getArguments().getString("subcategory") != null && !getArguments().getString("subcategory").isEmpty() && !getArguments().getString("subcategory").equals("")) {
                                int spinnerPostion3 = adapter3.getPosition(getArguments().getString("subcategory"));
                                subcategory_restaurant.setSelection(spinnerPostion3);
                                spinnerPostion3 = 0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("shopname") != null && !getArguments().getString("shopname").isEmpty() && !getArguments().getString("shopname").equals("")) {
                        shopname.setText(getArguments().getString("shopname"));
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("location") != null && !getArguments().getString("location").isEmpty()  && !getArguments().getString("location").equals("")) {
                        location.setText(getArguments().getString("location"));
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("email") != null && !getArguments().getString("email").isEmpty()  && !getArguments().getString("email").equals("")) {
                        email.setText(getArguments().getString("email"));
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("telephone") != null && !getArguments().getString("telephone").isEmpty()  && !getArguments().getString("telephone").equals("")) {
                        telephone.setText(getArguments().getString("telephone"));
                    }

                    finalOpening = getArguments().getString("opening");
                    finalClosing = getArguments().getString("closing");
                    finalDresscoding = getArguments().getString("dresscoding");
                    finalMusic = getArguments().getString("music");
                    finalOtherinfo = getArguments().getString("otherinfo");
                    finalFacebook = getArguments().getString("facebook");
                    finalMoneyperperson = getArguments().getString("moneyperperson");

                    if (getArguments().getString("smokingarea") != null && !getArguments().getString("smokingarea").isEmpty()) {
                        smokingarea = getArguments().getString("smokingarea");
                        if (smokingarea.equals("Y")) {
                            finalSmokingarea = 1;
                        } else if (smokingarea.equals("N")) {
                            finalSmokingarea = 0;
                        } else
                            finalSmokingarea = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalSmokingarea = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("parking") != null && !getArguments().getString("parking").isEmpty()) {
                        parking = getArguments().getString("parking");
                        if (parking.equals("Y")) {
                            finalParkingarea = 1;
                        } else if (parking.equals("N")) {
                            finalParkingarea = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalParkingarea = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalParkingarea = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("creditcards") != null && !getArguments().getString("creditcards").isEmpty()) {
                        creditcards = getArguments().getString("creditcards");
                        if (creditcards.equals("Y")) {
                            finalCreditcards = 1;
                        } else if (creditcards.equals("N")) {
                            finalCreditcards = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalCreditcards = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalCreditcards = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("takeout") != null && !getArguments().getString("takeout").isEmpty()) {
                        takeout = getArguments().getString("takeout");
                        if (takeout.equals("Y")) {
                            finalTakeout = 1;
                        } else if (takeout.equals("N")) {
                            finalTakeout = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalTakeout = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalTakeout = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("delivery") != null && !getArguments().getString("delivery").isEmpty()) {
                        delivery = getArguments().getString("delivery");
                        if (delivery.equals("Y")) {
                            finalDelivery = 1;
                        } else if (delivery.equals("N")) {
                            finalDelivery = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalDelivery = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalDelivery = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("freewifi") != null && !getArguments().getString("freewifi").isEmpty()) {
                        freewifi = getArguments().getString("freewifi");
                        if (freewifi.equals("Y")) {
                            finalFreewifi = 1;
                        } else if (freewifi.equals("N")) {
                            finalFreewifi = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalFreewifi = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalFreewifi = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("happyhour") != null && !getArguments().getString("happyhour").isEmpty()) {
                        happyhour = getArguments().getString("happyhour");
                        if (happyhour.equals("Y")) {
                            finalHappyhour = 1;
                        } else if (happyhour.equals("N")) {
                            finalHappyhour = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalHappyhour = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalHappyhour = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("outdoorseating") != null && !getArguments().getString("outdoorseating").isEmpty()) {
                        outdoorseating = getArguments().getString("outdoorseating");
                        if (outdoorseating.equals("Y")) {
                            finalOutdoorseating = 1;
                        } else if (outdoorseating.equals("N")) {
                            finalOutdoorseating = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalOutdoorseating = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalOutdoorseating = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("reservations") != null && !getArguments().getString("reservations").isEmpty()) {
                        reservations = getArguments().getString("reservations");
                        if (reservations.equals("Y")) {
                            finalReservations = 1;
                        } else if (reservations.equals("N")) {
                            finalReservations = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalReservations = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalReservations = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("appropriategroups") != null && !getArguments().getString("appropriategroups").isEmpty()) {
                        appropriategroup = getArguments().getString("appropriategroups");
                        if (appropriategroup.equals("Y")) {
                            finalAppropriategroup = 1;
                        } else if (appropriategroup.equals("N")) {
                            finalAppropriategroup = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalAppropriategroup = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalAppropriategroup = 2;
                    }

                    if (getArguments().getString("appropriatekids") != null && !getArguments().getString("appropriatekids").isEmpty()) {
                        appropriatekids = getArguments().getString("appropriatekids");
                        if (appropriatekids.equals("Y")) {
                            finalAppropriatekids = 1;
                        } else if (appropriatekids.equals("N")) {
                            finalAppropriatekids = 0;
                        }
                        else
                            finalAppropriatekids = 2;
                    }
                    else{
                        finalAppropriatekids = 2;
                    }
                }
                else{
                    finalOpening = "";
                    finalClosing = "";
                    finalMoneyperperson = "";
                    finalDresscoding = "";
                    finalMusic = "";
                    finalOtherinfo = "";
                    finalFacebook = "";
                    finalSmokingarea = 2;
                    finalParkingarea = 2;
                    finalCreditcards = 2;
                    finalTakeout = 2;
                    finalDelivery = 2;
                    finalFreewifi = 2;
                    finalHappyhour = 2;
                    finalOutdoorseating = 2;
                    finalReservations = 2;
                    finalAppropriategroup = 2;
                    finalAppropriatekids = 2;
                }
```

---

As you can see, I also posted the data that I already managed to save to Parse , so the data that are not being part of the problem. With that, you can notice, I didn't do something different from what I did with those data that worked fine.

Comment: i guess the .toString() is returning a null. Try replacing with .String in your addshopfragment

Comment: Please mark the relevant line where the exception raises in `AddShopFragment` class.

Comment: I am sorry @LuiggiMendoza, I forgot about that. This is the line: `                    if (!getArguments().getString("category").equals("Select:") && getArguments().getString("category") != null && !getArguments().getString("category").isEmpty() && !getArguments().getString("category").equals("")) {
`. It is right after the error that I post.

Comment: @Zedaiq , in the moreinfo button onclick listener, I change the `.toString()` to `                        if (String.valueOf(category.getSelectedItem()).equals("Select:") || String.valueOf(category.getSelectedItem()).isEmpty() || String.valueOf(category.getSelectedItem()) == null)
` but the error still occurs in the line that I posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems that `getArguments().getString("category")` is `null`. Check how you're doing your evaluation of the variable:

```
 if (!getArguments().getString("category").equals("Select:")
    //up here, you assume the variable is not null
    && getArguments().getString("category") != null
    //here you check if the variable is null or not, very late...
    && !getArguments().getString("category").isEmpty()
    //here you evaluate if the value of getArguments().getString("category") is not empty
    && !getArguments().getString("category").equals("")
    //here you check one more time if the value of getArguments().getString("category") is not empty) {
```

This can be solved simply by moving the null check before:

```
if (getArguments().getString("category") != null
    && !getArguments().getString("category").isEmpty()
    && !getArguments().getString("category").equals("")
    && !getArguments().getString("category").equals("Select:")) {
```

Or a better solution for these cases: compare the desired literal (or compile constant) `String` against your `String` parameter:

```
if ("Select:".equals(getArguments().getString("category")) {
```

Comment: I just removed from the big `if` the part about `null` and put it above this check as you suggest and everything works and being saved just fine. Thanks a lot.